# "solve" geometric shape

Tags: geometry

Well I have some "easy" geometrical shape. However I'm having troubles solving the equations. 
Basically I have 4 lines, which have a fixed length. Two bars cross each other, one bar is "fixed" in space (so 2 points are too). And finally from one point the angle can be changed. As can be seen below:

[image]

So once again: point A & D are fixed in place, I have to find an equation for point C, based on the input which is the angle $\alpha_2$. (And the lengths of AB, BC, AD & CD are fixed).

My first guess was to add the virtual line AC (once I know this length it is easy), and then solve it using the cosine law:

$$AB^2 + BC^2 - 2(AB)(BC)\cdot \cos(\beta) = AC^2 $$
$$DC^2 + AD^2 - 2(DC)(AD)\cdot \cos(\delta) = AC^2$$

However this leaves the angle $\beta$ and $\delta$ to be solved - which are unknowns.

I know this has to be easy - probably the result will be 2 lengths for AC (One as drawn, the other flipped around BD line). However I can't seem to find any solution, and all attempts quickly become a mess with pages of equations/matrices that have to be solved.

Comment: I wonder if this is a four bar linkage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-bar_linkage where AB sweeps out a circle and CD sweeps out a portion of a circle.

Comment: Well yes, but that doesn't help me solve the problem at hand.